Remove a phantom Microsoft work account linked to personal account
Whenever I sign into a Microsoft service (I'll use Teams as the example here), I get prompted to select if I am trying to use my work account or personal account.
If I try to select the work account (I do everything with the personal account) then I am presented with an AADSTS50020 error.

"AADSTS50020: User account [my email] from identity provider
'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Patrick's Company Name' and
cannot access the application Microsoft Teams in that tenant. The
account needs to be added in that tenant first"

This is not impacting the use of the personal account, but I get a big red exclamation in my personal Teams, which I really want gone, plus I am sick of the prompt. I just want to clean this up.
Some background that led to this.
I might not be correct here, but I am reasonably confident.
Whenever MS Teams first came out, maybe at the start of COVID times, I tried to use it and did something like create my own personal org called "Patrick's Company Name" (no idea how, maybe I did a trial of something, I tend to fiddle with MS stuff a lot over the years)
EDIT - I came across another post on this site with this screenshot, and I am reasonably confident that this is how I created the organisation when trying to trial Teams.
[https://i.sstatic.net/6aZhs.jpg]
If I try loging in to Azure admin to remove this gunk, I am told

You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead."

EDIT - I just reactivated my Azure account, but the tenant doesn't exist here.
I have no idea where it exists, but I sure can't access it.
So MS admin knows I don't have a work account.
But all the MS services that care think I do. Or might. Or something.
I have spent 90 minutes with MS support this morning, hoping they might escalate to someone who can clear this up, but then they just said "nope, can't help you, personal stuff still works, so please ignore the error warning".
Does anyone have any thoughts as to how I can clear this up?
I seem to recall signing up for a trial work account way back, but it wasn't aware of this old tenant/org and I couldn't get rid of it.
I figured I would come here and try ask some people that might know!
Happy to try any/all ideas. I can provide screenshots or even a network capture of anything that people might need to assist.

So your work tenant must be configured to allow remote connections; the fact it fails to authenticate suggests that's not the case. Ironically, your tenant's system administrator can make the required changes. If you create a new local account, does everything work? Microsoft does not provide technical support to end customers like us.

A new MSA is not required.  A new user account on the machine might be required.  It's trivial to transfer the contents of a profile to another profile.  It requires work, but it's entirely possible.

Thanks @Ramhound, I don't have access to the tenant. I even went and reactivated my Azure Admin account and the tenant simply doesn't exist there.
This is part of the problem, so I can't change anything there.

There can be a few problems here.

Its possible someone created/added your email address in an actual tenant and that still exists. (maybe you were added as a guest)

The tenant used to exist, you used it in your office, and connected this to your computer, so you still have a school/work account linked on your pc, but the tenant afterwards is gone.


I suspect the 2nd, but can't rule out the 1st.
In case its the second, there are 2 ways to test it.

From a different computer, going to portal.office.com, then logging in with your email address will redirect you to live.com (if this happens, its definitely 2, if it asks for personal or work/school account, its 1).
On your computer, go to Settings, Accounts, Access to School or Work, and see if you have that specific account listed. If so, try to remove it, that should resolve the issue. A reboot afterwards is possibly required.

Workaround:
Go to your personal account and login. Go to account settings, and locate your email address there. Add a new email address to your account and set it as primary. This new email address will become your username. Keep the old email address as alias, so you keep receiving emails to that email account.
With the username being different from the other account, you can now sign into teams with the new username, and the problem is gone.

Thanks LPChip.
Neither scenario is true. I signed up to use Teams when it first came out, and it guided me to create an organisation. I promptly decided it wasn't for me and left it alone for a few years, until I started using Teams for my personal account.
Now I have no way of removing this tenant or organisation.
I have actually changed the email address on my Microsoft personal account already, and this linkage hangs around no matter what email is on file, as the actual email I used for this back in the day is not used by me for anything anymore
